# Does option xcdraw to package xcolor do any good nowadays?

Tags: graphics, color, xdvi

Package [xcolor](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) has an option `xcdraw` whose documentation is:

```
Option xcdraw uses PostScript commands to draw frames and color boxes in case
of the dvips driver and PDF code to draw frames in case of the pdftex and
dvipdfm drivers. This is still experimental code that may confuse .dvi viewers.
```

And indeed making use of it confuses `xdvi` viewer (naturally, ps file from `dvips` will be ok).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[xcdraw]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\phantom{\rule{\linewidth}{1cm}}}
\end{document}
```

Here is when compiling with `latex` and viewing the `dvi` file:

> [image: Blockquote]

As the graphicx drivers for various engines are actively maintained (xetex, pdftex), is using `xcdraw` option still a good thing nowadays ?

Comment: No, it was only for special cases, years ago.

Comment: @Herbert could you make this into an answer ? (I need to link back to it from elsewhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it was only for special cases, years ago. However, Uwe Kern, the author of the package is also no more active for years and this option will still be present as is until no one will take over maintainership.

Comment: +1 I suspected that... too bad for my other issue with xcolor which is about `\fbox` not usable in moving arguments (try `\section{\fbox{A}}` with and without xcolor).